# Kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2)

Tags: raspbian, root

What i can do? I know I can use keyboard to run “check and repair” but in this moment raspberry not see usb keyboard and I don’t have card reader near me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need another SDCard, a USB SDCard reader, an RPi, a copy of Raspbian and [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).

Use Etcher to write Raspbian to your new SDCard. Insert that in your RPi and boot it.

Once booted insert the broken SDCard in your USB reader and insert that in your RPi.

The GUI will attempt to mount the filesystems it finds on the SDCard.

Open an lxterminal window and run the following command `sudo -s` to get a root shell. `umount /dev/sda1;umount /dev/sda2` to undo the auto-mount. Then `fsck -f -y /dev/sda1;fsck -f -y /dev/sda2` to fix the damage.

Shutdown swap SDCards, keep calm and carry on.

Keep the spare rescue system SDCard in your toolkit collection. Get a third SDCard and use the GUI SDCard copier to take a bootable backup to that third SDCard.

You can do that on a laptop if you can boot a copy of Linux on it from a USB stick or a live CD.

Comment: Now i dont have laptop and i say raspberry dont see keyboard, i mean i cannot write in raspberry terminal.

Comment: Time to go shopping.

Comment: alredy, chinese ninja`s now delivering my cardreader in Russia ¯\_(ツ)_/¯